# I'm using Windows 10 why does this note appear when installing SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server, windows-10, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2017 on Windows 10, when this note appears:

> Your operating system is not supported by SQL Server 2017

[sql-server 2017 edition download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkjkA.jpg)

Comment: Do you have 32-bit Windows?

Comment: @GSerg yes im using 32bit.

Comment: Then you cannot install SQL Server 2017, because, like it's explained in the [system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#pmosr), it's 64-bit only. The last SQL Server that had a 32-bit version is 2014.

Comment: @GSerg  but im in Desperate need for it, what version can work with windows 10 32bit, Please help

Comment: Like I said, it's [2014](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42299).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017):

"Windows client operating systems, for example Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 are available as 32-bit or 64-bit architectures. All SQL Server features are supported on 64-bit client operating systems."

That is, not all SQL Server features will be availabl in 32-bit architectures.

Comment: That is a weird part to quote, to the degree where it makes it look wrong. The SQL Server engine is not available on 32-bit at all. Only connectivity tools are available, which would let you to connect to an SQL Server running on some other computer.